# Как определить, на какой странице будет находиться индекс в выборке?

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим, у меня произвольная выборка из таблицы с делением на страницы по 15 позиций. Лимит в базе будет звучать, соответственно как 15*(**n**-1),15.
выборка начинается с **id** 168 и заканчивается 10, а сортировка там по третьему полю

Как определить, при каком **n**, мой индекс **id** попадёт в множество на выходе?

На ум приходит только перебрать в цикле; а есть ли способ сделать это одним SQL запросом?

Answer (score 2):

```
n = m / 15
```

разумеется

Answer (score 0):

Нет, в данном случае только перебором.

Классическая задача "как мне после создания объекта показать его в списке".

Да никак. Вместо этого сделай flash-message с текстом "что-то создано/изменено" с ссылку на это "что-то". Если пользователю приспичит, он сам найдёт.

Если очень очень надо быстро найти недавно созданные или изменённые "что-то", то выдавай пользователям специальный список "что менял в последнее время" и предусмотри сортировку в списках "по дате последнего изменения"